# How to hide number of comments text in Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a website by using Wordpress CMS (wordpress.org). My question is how to hide or remove number of comments text above the comments elements. See below image.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you know how to use chrome/browser developer tools  to inspect html ? if yes then find the class or id applied to this, and go to your style.css in worpdress admin -> appearance -editor .. and write css  .className or #id { display:none;}

Comment: Thanks Abhirathore,

I tried the same thing using Firefox browser. But I was failed to inspect the correct source files.

Comment: what is your website ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide number of comments text by css like.

```
.comments-area .comments-title{
    display: none;
}
```

Or you can remove code from `comment.php` file.

```
 <h2 class="comments-title">
        <?php
            printf( _nx( 'One thought on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', '%1$s thoughts on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'twentyfifteen' ),
                number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ), get_the_title() );
        ?>
</h2>
```

Find the line something like it depends on your theme developer which tag his used. try to find out `h1`,`h2`,`h3`,`h4`,`h5`,`h6` and remove it.

if you can't find any line with this tag. please put your `comment.php` file code so i can give a exact solution.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you Renish,

Css method not works for my theme. but your second solution is really helpful to identify the exact php lines in comments.php file.